# SQL Server -> .Net int conversion

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, .net-3.5

I had a line of code in a WinForms app (target platform x86) I made which contained this...

```
if (dtMax.Rows[0][0] != System.DBNull.Value) 
      iPrevMax = (Int64)(dtMax.Rows[0][0]);
```

I know that dtMax.Rows[0][0] will be the `MAX` of a column in a given table in SQL Server. The datatype of the column is `INT`.

Now - this line of code at some point threw an exception. I don't know what the exception was as I was on holiday and nobody took note!! Angry face.

However the line was changed to....

```
if (dtMax.Rows[0][0] != System.DBNull.Value) 
      iPrevMax = Convert.ToInt64(dtMax.Rows[0][0]);
```

...And now it works.

I understand a few things...

- .Net equivalent of SQLServer `INT` is `Int32` - so should really have been unboxing to that.
- `Convert` will generally be "safer" than unboxing

But I don't understand *why would this line of code work originally and then at some point fail to unbox?* What could *possible* reasons be - in spite of annoyingly not knowing the actual exception...

Comment: How is the database constructed, meaning, do you have a tool that creates all the tables, a script, or do you instruct someone to do it, meaning, could there be a difference in table definition between test and production?

Comment: And how sure are you that this line of code has actually ever executed, before it crashed?

Comment: And I question your "and now it works" conclusion. If you're unable to reproduce the error, you can't safely say that it works. For instance, what if the `dtMax` table contained no rows, so the problem was never that you tried to unbox/cast the wrong type, just that there was no data at that time? If it "worked" before you changed it, and it "works" afterwards, how can you tell that what you did actually helped?

Comment: Table was created manually with CREATE TABLE script very simply. Actually the code executed on *my* machine (which is Win7) and failed on user's machine - though it did work once I think. If the `dtMax` table had no rows then then query I am executing would still return a row with `dtMax.Rows[0][0]` equal to SQL `NULL` - which would handled by both versions of the code.

Comment: User's machine is XP. Do you thin that could explain it?

Comment: No, I doubt it. I think it's most likely the cast though, just not 100% sure.

Comment: OK - So user said it worked once. But the table will have been empty then - returning NULL (and not performing cast/unbox/convert). So my question should really be - How come unboxing SQL `int` as `Int64` works on Win7 and fails on XP?